# Build Complex Project Filter via CMake

Tags: cmake

I built a C++ project which the file structure as same as the image

[image: File Structure]

Every Cpp file is an isolated executable file. And I would like to build a project filter as same as the file structure via CMake.

The following code sample shows the root CMakeLists.txt I wrote for this purpose:

```
project(Samples)

source_group( "Samples\\ClientSamples" FILES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ClientSamples/ClientSamplesMain.cpp )
source_group( "Samples\\GenericSamples" FILES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/GenericSamples/GenericSamplesMain.cpp )
source_group( "Samples\\ServerSamples" FILES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ServerSamples/ServerSamplesDemo.cpp ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ServerSamples/HttpServerSample.cpp )

add_subdirectory(GenericSamples)
add_subdirectory(ServerSamples)
add_subdirectory(ClientSamples)
```

And the result didn't match my expectation.
    The result is

[image: Filter Now].

So, is there a way to reach the goal?

Best Regards.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please give an example of your `add_executable()` calls? From the solution explorer it doesn't look like you have defined any targets.

Comment: If no add_executable() then is there another way to reach the goal?
I've explored that the source_group() need add_executable/library function.
And as well I've explored that the CMake makes every single executable a folder (Ex. HttpServerSample and ServerSamples Demo are in a same folder) even I use the same source group for the two files in a CMakeLists.txt.